# How do you select the file name of a maven jar-with-dependencies?

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin

I am creating an executable jar using the jar-with-dependencies component of the maven-assembly-plugin during the package phase of my maven lifecycle.  However, I can't see a way to configure the name of the jar that is output.  It appears to always be something like

```
appname-1.1-r1011-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

How can i configure it to be something else, like perhaps

```
appname-1.1-r1011.jar
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can set the [`appendAssemblyId`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html#appendAssemblyId) parameter to `false` in the [`maven-assembly-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to avoid the *"jar-with-dependencies"* suffix.

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```